# Why does AAC render grainy output on my system?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, aac

I have two different systems (Windows 10 LTSB and Windows Server 2012) running the same version of ffmpeg and I'm running the following command in both of them:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -vn -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 output.mp4
```

(with "input.mp3" being the same exact file)

In this system, I'm getting grainy, poor quality output, while in the other system I'm getting clear high quality results.

It happens even with all other versions of ffmpeg: Grainy results in this system, nice results in the other system. Same exact command.

Is there a logic explanation to this?

Win10 Log: https://pastebin.com/GY8p3S9p

Server 2012 Log: https://pastebin.com/BHKwTdug

Comment: Share full log of both runs.

Comment: Added logs to post.

Comment: As suggested by an expert friend, I used -aac_coder twoloop parameter in my Windows 10 system and the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by an expert friend, I used -aac_coder twoloop parameter in my Windows 10 system and the problem has been fixed.